# How to remove a span in-place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following input:

```
<p>
  <span class="highlight">
    Some text <b>that can have formatted components too</b>.
  </span>
  And some more text here of course.
</p>
```

And I want to achieve the following output:

```
<p>
    Some text <b>that can have formatted components too</b>.
    And some more text here of course.
</p>
```

I am using jquery and it has a `.unwrap()` function, but if I go
`$('.highlight').unwrap()` it removes `<p>`. :(

Manually hacking the DOM seems like a hassle. Do you know any short solution?

Comment: `$(".highlight").parent("p").html($(".highlight").text());`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the use of `.contents()` you'll get the elements inside of the parent element you want to remove.

```
$(".highlight").contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: For safety you can include a second line: `$(".highlight").remove();` to handle the (rare) special case `<span class="highlight"></span>`. unwrap does not remove it because it does not have any content.

Answer (score 2):

try replace with

```
$('.highlight').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: That works, but it is a lot more complicated than Spokey's solution.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `.replaceWith`, +1.

Comment: Interestingly enough, replaceWith too only works with nodes that have content. (So here too adding `$('.highlight').remove();` is suggested, see my comment on Spokey's answer)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PhG8w/ would be my choice. You can gather the elements directly from `.replaceWith()` and then remove them, so spans with no content also disappear. If someone finds this irritating, from the docs: _Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed._

Answer (score 0):

You can simply can do this by using jQuery.

```
var cnt = $(".highlight").contents();

$(".highlight").replaceWith(cnt);
```

Quick links to the documentation:

- [contents( )](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents) : jQuery
- [replaceWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceWith)( content : [String | Element | jQuery] ) : jQuery

Comment: I tested and it only works with a single element highlighted. (and if I had only a single highlight, I would have marked it by id="highlight" in the question)